# sort query result without selecting that column but sort by that column?

Tags: sql, database, sorting, db2

I have a query, I have to sort the result from the DB2 database. The query will select the columns `empname,salary,status`. But I have to sort the result using order by empno
But the query is not working.. This is the query.

```
select empname, salary, status from emp where salary>5000 order by empno
```

Can you update the query to sort by `empno` without using it in selecting columns?

Comment: Remove the dot and try again.

Comment: Please post the table's create SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your time.. It is working..I selected from multiple tables but the empno is ambiguous.. Now updated.. working..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your syntax seems correct to me except dot(.) at the end. After removing dot if doesn't work...

Try something like

```
SELECT empname, salary, status
  FROM (SELECT   *
            FROM emp
        ORDER BY empno)
 WHERE salary > 5000
```

Comment: HI jaychapani, Your query is not working.. Can you update it correctly ?

Comment: As per IBM's documentation "The column specified in the ORDER BY clause does not need to be included in the SELECT clause."

Comment: Can you just post screen print of result of query "select * from emp"

Comment: Thanks for your time.. It is working..I selected from multiple tables but the empno is ambiguous.. Now updated.. working..

Comment: @Mr.Chowdary &  jaychapani  ORDER BY in a subselect is not guaranteed to do anything. Tables have no order, result sets do.

Comment: This will sometimes work... but you can't depend on it as the order by is not guaranteed to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

Another syntax that may be easier, depending on how you think about it is using the `with` keyword. This explicitly creates a named temporary table with the desired ordering, then queries from that. The order of the new query will be the same as the temporary tables ordering.

```
WITH temp_table AS (SELECT   *
            FROM emp
        ORDER BY empno)

SELECT empname, salary, status
  FROM temp_table
 WHERE salary > 5000;
```

The answer by @jaychapani is more concise and functionally does the same thing, but the `with` syntax is powerful for quite a few other use cases and visually separates the two, which can be helpful especially if you have a long subquery that does other things.

Answer (score 1):

I used below query to solve this problem.
In this case we can sort query result without displaying the column:

```sql
WITH temp_table
     AS (select distinct(s1.Name),s1.id
         from students s1
         where marks>75
         order by right(s1.Name ,3) asc,s1.id asc
        )

SELECT Name
  FROM temp_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but the fastest way on DB is something like this:

```
SELECT empname, salary, status
FROM (
    select empname, salary, status, empno 
    from emp 
    where salary > 5000 
    order by empno ASC
)
```

Answer (score -3):

try this

```
select empname, salary, status from emp where salary>5000 order by empno asc
```

make sure that columns and table  name really exist.

have a look at: [ORDER BY clause](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/sqlp/rbafyorderby.htm)

Best Regards

Comment: the dot was removed and i added asc (asceding) or use desc for  descending order of your data.

Comment: I think not all SQL servers supports order by without specifying column in select